# Can't forward real client IP Address in a Blazor docker compose configuration with Nginx

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx, docker-compose, blazor

I'm having some trouble to set up a Blazor server app to receive the real IP Address in a docker compose configuration with nginx in a reverse proxy configuration. The blazor app is running in an specific `ipam` network configuration. The Blazor app seems to be receiving nginx private IP Address inside the docker configuration, instead of the external client IP Address.

I have tried nearly everything I found in Google:

1. added the    `options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor;` flags and `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` in the Blazor `Program.cs` file
2. Added the previous `ipam` ip addresses to Blazor's `KnownProxies` and `KnownNetworks
3. Added the `real_ip_header` and `set_real_ip_from` in the `nginx.config` as suggested by many answers I found on Google
4. Added `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` to the `nginx.config` file to forward the Client IP Address

But the Blazor server, which is listening in port `5077` always retrieves the proxy address, `127.28.1.1` which corresponds with the Docker `ipam` network, instead of the Client Ip Address, which in my case should be `127.0.0.1` as I'm running docker in my local machine.

[image]

I will attach the configuration I have as well as a [`.zip`](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/sPjKk2YW#link) with all the reprocucible project in case:

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using NginxBlazorTest.Data;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();


builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    //options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;

    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor;
    //options.ForwardLimit = null;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();

    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.1.0"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.1.1"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.1.2"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.1.3"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.1.0"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.1.1"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.1.2"));
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.1.3"));
    

    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.0.0"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.0.1"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.0.2"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.28.0.3"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.0.0"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.0.1"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.0.2"), 8));
    options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.0.3"), 8));    
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5077

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NginxBlazorTest/NginxBlazorTest.csproj", "NginxBlazorTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./NginxBlazorTest/./NginxBlazorTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/NginxBlazorTest"
RUN dotnet build "./NginxBlazorTest.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
RUN dotnet publish "./NginxBlazorTest.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NginxBlazorTest.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginxblazortest:
    container_name: nginxblazortest
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}nginxblazortest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NginxBlazorTest/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - frontend_network 
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development      
      - URLS=http://+:5077;   
      - HTTP_PORT:5077;
 
  nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx:alpine     
      networks:
      - frontend_network 
      ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
      - 443:443
      volumes:
      - ./Nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro  
      - ./Nginx/proxy_params:/etc/nginx/proxy_params:ro  
      depends_on:
      - nginxblazortest      
networks:
  frontend_network: 
     ipam:
      driver: host
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.1.0/16
          ip_range: 172.28.1.0/24   

volumes:
  conf:
    driver: local      
  vhost:
    driver: local      
  certs:
    driver: local
  html:
    driver: local
```

nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;

events 
{
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http 
{ 
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    upstream nginxblazortest 
    {
        server nginxblazortest:5077;        
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

        set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.0;
        set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.1;
        set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.2;
        set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.3;
        set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.0/16;
        set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.0/24;
        set_real_ip_from  127.0.0.1;
        set_real_ip_from  ::1;    
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:172.28.1.0;
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:172.28.1.1;
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:172.28.1.2;
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:172.28.1.3;
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:172.28.1.0/16;
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:172.28.1.0/24;
        set_real_ip_from  ::ffff:127.0.0.1;
        real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on;

        location / {      
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://nginxblazortest/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

I added some middleware in the Blazor app as suggested in the comments to capture the request headers as fast as they arrive without further manipulation, and the IPs are wrong, they still reflect the nGinx container IP instead of the Client IP's localhost address

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your `docker-compose.yml`, you've used `ipam` with a custom subnet and IP range.If you don't have a specific need for this, consider removing the custom IPAM configuration and let Docker handle the networking.  only add the IP of your NGINX container to the `KnownProxies`. In the `nginx.conf`, you have multiple redundant lines like `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`.

```
http {
       ...
       upstream nginxblazortest {
           server nginxblazortest:5077;        
       }

       server {
           ...
           set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.0/24;
           real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
           real_ip_recursive on;

           location / {      
               include proxy_params;
               proxy_pass http://nginxblazortest/;
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
           }
       }
   }
```

Remove all known proxies and networks except the Docker subnet.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
   {
       options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor;
       options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
       options.KnownProxies.Clear();

       options.KnownNetworks.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.28.1.0"), 24)); 
   });
```

Make sure that no other middleware or service is adding to the `X-Forwarded-For` header after it gets to Blazor. try deploying the project to some different server and make a test.

Comment: Hi Jalpa, thanks for the message. The fact that I had redundant lines there it was because of the multiple tests I was doing as I didn't get it to work with any of them, but yes, you are right, most of those lines are not necessary at the end. I was using the IPAM configuration so I can know in advance what the IP range of the Nginx proxy server would be in order to add it to the KnownProxy list, otherwise Docker might choose a random IP. I have made the changes you suggested, but still no luck. Thanks anyways.

Comment: could you try enable logging In Nginx, you can add the `$http_x_real_ip` and `$http_x_forwarded_for` variables to your log format to see what Nginx is sending to your Blazor application. In Blazor, you might want to log both `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` and the `X-Forwarded-For` header to see what you're receiving.for a testing try running both Nginx and your Blazor app outside of Docker on your local machine. If the IP is correct in that setup, the issue might be related to the Docker networking configuration. @FernandoUrkijo

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purpose, try and create a [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in your Blazor application to log the values of the `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers. That way, you can check if these headers are reaching your Blazor application with the correct values.

In `Program.cs`, after `var app = builder.Build();`, insert the custom middleware code:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

// Custom middleware to log headers
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Retrieve the values of the headers
    var xRealIp = context.Request.Headers["X-Real-IP"].FirstOrDefault();
    var xForwardedFor = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault();

    // Log the values of the headers
    Console.WriteLine($"X-Real-IP: {xRealIp}, X-Forwarded-For: {xForwardedFor}");

    // Continue processing
    await next.Invoke();
});

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
// rest of the code
```

Run your Blazor application and make a request to it through your Nginx reverse proxy.
Check the console output or logs to see the values of the `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers.

- If the middleware is logging the correct client IP address, then the headers are being forwarded correctly by Nginx, and the issue might be with how the Blazor application is processing these headers.
- If the headers are not showing the correct IP, or are missing, then the issue might still be with the Nginx configuration, or possibly with Docker networking.

The idea is to get a clear insight into whether the correct headers and values are reaching your Blazor application.

---

> The middleware shows IPs with the nGinx proxy address instead of the client Address 127.0.0.1

Given that the middleware shows the Nginx proxy address instead of the client address `127.0.0.1`, the issue likely resides in the Nginx configuration or the interaction between Nginx and Docker networking.

Make sure the [`real_ip_header` and `set_real_ip_from` directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) are correctly set in the Nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

    set_real_ip_from  172.28.1.0/24;  # Adjust to match your Docker network
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    location / {      
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://nginxblazortest/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

- The `set_real_ip_from` directives have been consolidated to a single line with the CIDR notation `172.28.1.0/24`, which should cover the IP range of your Docker network. That simplification makes the configuration cleaner and easier to manage.
- The redundant `proxy_set_header` directives have been removed from the `location` block. Now, only one line each for `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` remain, which should be sufficient to forward the client IP to your Blazor application.
- The `real_ip_header` and `real_ip_recursive` directives remain unchanged, as they are correctly set to handle the `X-Forwarded-For` header and recursive processing of the `set_real_ip_from` directive.

For testing, consider using [host networking in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/), which makes the Nginx container use the host's network stack. That might help with forwarding the correct client IP.
Update your `docker-compose.yml` to include `network_mode: host` for the Nginx service:

```yaml
...
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    network_mode: host
    ...
```

Switching to `network_mode: host` for the Nginx service while keeping other services on the custom `frontend_network` network can introduce a discrepancy in how networking is handled between these services. When you use `network_mode: host`, the Nginx container will share the network stack with the host machine, whereas the other service(s) will be on a separate Docker-managed network (`frontend_network` in this case).

In the `nginx.conf`, you would then need to make sure the `proxy_pass` directive points to the correct address and port where the `nginxblazortest` service is accessible from the host's network, which may require updating based on the new network configuration.

That adjustment might help in forwarding the real client IP, but it is essential to be aware of the trade-offs and make sure the services can still communicate as necessary.

---

> I updated yesterday Docker Desktop changed the driver to host in the networks section of the docker-compose file, and I have started to receive the 192.168.65.0/24 IP which corresponds to the Docker Subnet, but still haven't seen 127.0.0.1.
>
> I can't use the approach you suggested on `network_mode` as the `nginx` and `thefrontend` have to be in the same network so `nginx` now, where to redirect the upstream.

A client IP  `192.168.65.0/24` instead of `127.0.0.1` is likely due to the way Docker handles networking and NAT (Network Address Translation), described, for instance, in "[Going Behind The Scenes of Docker Networking](https://argus-sec.com/blog/engineering-blog/docker-networking-behind-the-scenes/)" by [Omri Kazelnik](https://il.linkedin.com/in/omri-kazelnik).
When a request reaches the Nginx container, it has already been through Docker's network stack, which alters the source IP.

Inspect the logs for both Nginx and Docker to see if there are any errors or warnings related to networking or IP forwarding.

For testing, by using Docker's `-p` or `--publish` flag, you can bind the Nginx container directly to the desired host port. That may help in getting the actual client IP address.

```bash
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

In `docker-compose.yml`, this would be:

```yaml
# 
nginx:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
#
```

If you are running the setup on your local machine (again, for testing purposes), you could hard-code the client IP in a custom header using Nginx:

```
location / {
    #
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 127.0.0.1;
    #
}
```

If the issue persists, you might want to explore other reverse proxy solutions like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), which might handle Docker networking differently and could solve the IP forwarding issue.

Comment: Hi VonC, Thanks for the answer, I have added the peace of code  you suggested in an update in the question, but unfortunately no luck yet. Sounds as you say, to be an nGinx problem, but can't fathom what could it be.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijo By "no luck", do you mean the headers are not showing the correct IP? Or are they missing?

Comment: They show the nGinx proxy address instead of the client Address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijo I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the update again. I updated yesterday Docker Desktop changed the `driver` to  `host` in the networks section of the docker compose file, and I have started to receive the `192.168.65.0/24` IP which corresponds to the Docker Subnet, but still haven't seen 127.0.0.1. I can't use the approach you suggested on `network_mode` as the `nginx` and the`frontend` have to be in the same network so `nginx` now where to redirect the upstream.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijo OK. I have updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Hi, at the end of the day I didn't find a way to solve this issue and I decided to keep using nGinx, but I'm sending the IP in a custom cookie from Javascript using https://find-ip.openjavascript.info/. It is not ideal, and is not bulletproof, but can't imagine any other way to do it. Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful and it had very valid points!

Comment: @FernandoUrkijo  That does seem like pragmatic workaround by using a JavaScript-based solution to send the IP address in a custom cookie.  Well done. While this approach may not be ideal or completely bulletproof, it should be a suitable interim solution, especially if other methods to resolve the issue within the Docker and Nginx environment have not been successful.